# Programmatically powering off an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is it possible to programmatically power off an iPhone or does Apple disallow this?

If Apple disallows this, is it possible to programmatically mute the sound on an iPhone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have any evidence for that, but this would involve modifying the "UserExperience" - which is something **that Apple never would allow** (and why still many people jailbreak their phones).

And this involves "power off" as well as "mute sound" - because both could destroy the UX (you wait for an important call, but application X broke the sound).

Answer (score 5):

The iPhone applications you create with the official SDK are sandboxes in and of themselves. Walled off sandboxes with barbed wire.

You won't be able to turn off the power. And muting sounds other than your own applications' sounds amounts to being able to turn off the iPod playback.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to programmatically power off apple iPhone or does apple dissalow this. If apple disallow this is it possible to programmatically mute the sound on iPhone?

Apple prevents you from affecting the functionality of other apps and the core phone functions. When in doubt, if you want to do something phone-wide, you can't.

Plus, to mute the phone, you'd also have to figure out some way of making the physical mute switch on the side of the phone match the phone's mute setting. That's not going to happen with software!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how powering down the device and muting the device are reasonable alternatives in your app, but the bottom line is that you can't power down the device.  However, you can mute the sound of your own app or the iPod app using the MPMusicPlayerController class.

The code looks like this for your app:

```
MPMusicPlayerController *player = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
player.volume = 0.0f;
```

And, this for the iPod:

```
MPMusicPlayerController *player = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
player.volume = 0.0f;
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything you do that affects anything external to your application wont make it through the approval process (besides push notifications).  You can certainly mute the sound in your app by simply pausing, stopping, or setting the volume to zero for all sounds you are playing.  If you mean make the phone be mute globally, no.

Answer (score 1):

You can't turn the device off through software. You can set the music playback volume with the MPMusicPlayerController class, the docs suggest you can't change the volume of the
iPod player though.