# switch off iPhone by the programming

Tags: iphone

Can i switch off the iPhone by the programming if yes then how?

Comment: That sounds like madness. Why on earth would you like to do that?

Comment: i ask this question because i think on this.We can shut down our system programitically in many languages. So for learning, i ask this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [programmatically powering off iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613989/programmatically-powering-off-iphone)

Comment: Ok, so you don't plan on implementing it, but are just interested if it's possible? Fair enough. Go ahead and accept "willcodejavaforfood"'s answer, because that is the information you are looking for.

Comment: It will be funny if user tried to leave your application .your app can always switch of his mobile for his disrespect!!!!      Apple will never allow this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No that is not possible